# Is there a two level labeling in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

In latex there is a two level labeling:

- section, subsection, subsubsecton...
- paragraph, subparagraph, subsubparagrpah...

is there such a way in Microsoft Word?

Now in Word I can only see Header 1, Header 2, Header 3....

Comment: What is your practical problem?  Do you have a document structure you can't achieve in Word?

Comment: @MátéJuhász I'm composing a file as a collection of posts. Each post has its original Header 1, Header 2, etc; while the collection of posts also has a hierarchy.  That's why I hope to have a two level labeling. Now I use Header 1-4 for the first layer, then Header 5 onwards for the 2nd layer (that is the original Header 1 etc from each posts).

Comment: There is no hierarchy for sections in Word, so I think what you're doing is the optimal process.